# change output names from getSymbols in R

Tags: r, quantmod

Im trying to import several tickers from yahoo finance but I want to customize the data.frames names to create a pattern like: 'AAPL_price', 'SIEN_price'.

I tried with a single import and it works, but then I loop it and doesn't. Any ideas?

```
AHNR_price<-getSymbols('AHNR',
       from='2016-01-01',to='2016-12-30',
       symbol.lookup = TRUE,
       warnings = TRUE,auto.assign=FALSE)
```

It delivers a single data.frame called 'AHNR_price', that's what Im looking for with the rest of my tickers.

Then I try to import all the symbols in the "default" way and it works too

```
getSymbols(Symbols = symbols,from='2016-01-01',to='2016-12-30',warnings = TRUE,auto.assign=TRUE)
```

But then, the loop doesn't. Although it doesn't deliver any warning or error.

```
for(i in seq_along(symbols)) {
  Symbolprice<-paste0(symbols[i],'_price')
  Symbolprice<-getSymbols(Symbols=symbols[i],
             from='2016-01-01',to='2016-12-30',
             warnings = TRUE,auto.assign=TRUE)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not work because you overwrite Symbolprice and don't change its name.

This does what you want. You can easily delete the original objects without "_price" in its name.

```
library(quantmod)

symbols <- c("QQQ", "AAPL", "SIEN")

getSymbols(symbols, auto.assign = T)

for(sym in symbols) {
  d <- mget(sym)
  assign(x = paste0(sym, "_price"), value = d)
}
```